# How to make json's file like keypoint coco or MPII data

Tags: dataset, keypoint

Hi I'm trying to create a medical image Keypoint Dataset. I don't know how to create a json file like "person_keypoints_train2014.json" of coco dataset?

I tried some tools loike VGG Image Annotator with keypoint marks, but the lines to connect the keypoint as well as the observed or hidden points cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the tool I've been working on called [COCO Annotator](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/). It supports key-points and segmentation.

Comment: Thanks @jsbroks. I will try to use it.